# Is there any way to localize numbers and dates in dart?

Tags: dart

In C# we have CultureInfo which affects the way ToString() works for dates and numbers
eg. you can set CurrentCulture by doing:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pl-PL");;
```

Is there any equivalent for the above in dart?

EDIT:

1. Short answer is: use intl package (thanks to all for answers)
2. As Alan Knight pointed below setting locale "by thread" does not make sense in Dart since we do not control threads explicite.
3. At the moment i write this NumberFormating is work in progress as far as i understand it

Comment: Instead of editing your question, you can mark my answer as "Accepted" by pressing the green checkmark/tick icon on the left side of my answer (below the up/down arrows).

Comment: @KaiSellgren indeed - the problem is, more than one response fully answer my question (e.g. you are not mentioning NumberFormat). Anyway thanks for  the tip :)

Comment: You can always edit answers as well. Generally you choose any answer you want that you feel was the best answer, whether that was mine or someone else's. If there's no answer that actually solved your problem you can keep the question "unanswerred". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`intl`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/intl/Intl.html) library will offer you this, although it doesn't affect the behavior of `toString()`.

Here's an example:

Add as a dependency to your `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  intl: any # You might specify some version instead of _any_
```

Then a code sample:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';

main() {
  initializeDateFormatting("en_US", null).then((_) {
    var formatter = new DateFormat.yMd().add_Hm();
    print(formatter.format(new DateTime.now()));
  });
}
```

The output looks like this:

> 07/10/1996 12:08 PM

Comment: And for numbers you can use the [NumberFormat class](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html) like this: `var formatter = NumberFormat("#,###", "hu_HU");`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as per the previous entry the Intl library is what you want. You can set the default locale, or use the withLocale method to set it within a function. Setting it by thread doesn't work, as there are no threads. The other major difference is that, since this is all downloaded into the browser, you don't automatically have all the locale data available, but have to go through an async initialization step to load the data. That will probably be switched over to use the new lazy loading features soon.

Also, the locale doesn't affect the system toString() operation but rather you have to use a DateFormat object to print the date. And as it's still work in progress, NumberFormat doesn't work properly for locales yet, but should soon.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/intl/Intl.html

From the page: 
The Intl class provides a common entry point for internationalization related tasks.